# List comprehension - Iterating over nested lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a function that searches nested lists in their entirety to return all lists that contain a certain word, but this only returns `None`

```
word = "what song?"
def searchSong(mp3_list, word):
    search = input((word))
    match = [i for i in mp3_list if search in i[2]] 
for confirmed in match:
    print(confirmed[0],'\n', confirmed[1],'\n', confirmed[2])

print(searchSong(mp3_list, word))
```

When I do comparison testing, the `match` variable still returns nothing:

```
mp3_list = [["Eric Clapton","Tears in heaven","Rush"],["Neil Young", "Heart of gold", "Harvest"]]
match = [i for i in mp3_list if 'heaven' in i[2]]
print(match)      #returns []
```

But this works, despite the syntax appearing exactly the same:

```
li = [["0", "20", "ar"], ["20", "40", "asdasd"], ["50", "199", "bar"]]
match = [i for i in li if 'ar' in i[2]]
print(match)     #returns [['0', '20', 'ar'], ['50', '199', 'bar']]
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: "heaven" is not in `i[2]` in your first example, it is in `i[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'heaven' is present in the second element in `["Eric Clapton","Tears in heaven","Rush"]`, but you're checking the *third* element (`i[2]`).  Python arrays are indexed starting from 0, not 1.  (But you appear to know this, as your second example looks for "ar" in `i[2]`, which is correct.)

Also, `searchSong()` doesn't *return* anything, therefore it always returns None by default.

Answer (score 1):

```
mp3_list = [["Eric Clapton","Tears in heaven","Rush"],["Neil Young", "Heart of gold", "Harvest"]]
match = [i for i in mp3_list for j in i if 'heaven' in j]
match
Out[7]: [['Eric Clapton', 'Tears in heaven', 'Rush']]


li = [["0", "20", "ar"], ["20", "40", "asdasd"], ["50", "199", "bar"]]
match = [i for i in li for j in i if 'ar' in j]
match
Out[10]: [['0', '20', 'ar'], ['50', '199', 'bar']]
```

Comment: I didnt think of using nested for loop inside a list comprehension, thank you MaThMaX :)

Comment: @AJP, this way, it works no matter your `key` located on which index of your inner list. But John Gordon is right, Python index always starts from 0